# ng-repeat not updated on array change in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

My goal is to use `websockets to receive some`JSON` through and update a table in a directive.

I've created a simple directive :-

```
app.directive("penaltyTable", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/Content/AngularPartials/Coach/PenaltyLine.html',
    controller: function() {
        this.players = [];
        var penaltyController = this;

        var uri = "ws://localhost.local/api/CoachesTracker/10";

        //Initialize socket
        var websocket = new WebSocket(uri);

        // Error handling stuff here.....

        //Socket message handler
        websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            penaltyController.players = data;
        };
    },
    controllerAs: 'penaltyTrackerCtrl'
};
});
```

I've created a simple template PenaltyLine.html

```
<table class="penalty-table">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="player in penaltyTrackerCtrl.players">
        <td>{{player.Number}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td>{{player.Name}}</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

My web-socket receives data OK from the server, appears to update the players array however the template is never updated to display new data.

I think I am learning to run before I can walk with angular! Is there something basic I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger a digest. A safe way of doing this is using $timeout with a 0-time delay. You can also call the code in $scope.$apply (checking that a digest is not already running). $timeout, while ugly, is generally preferred.

```
app.directive("penaltyTable", function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/Content/AngularPartials/Coach/PenaltyLine.html',
    controller: function() {
        this.players = [];
        var penaltyController = this;

        var uri = "ws://localhost.local/api/CoachesTracker/10";

        //Initialize socket
        var websocket = new WebSocket(uri);

        // Error handling stuff here.....

        //Socket message handler
        websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                penaltyController.players = data;
            });
        };
    },
    controllerAs: 'penaltyTrackerCtrl'
};
});
```

The reason is that AngularJS doesn't know that your websocket just got a message, and hence doesn't know that anything happened in the "Angular" way of data binding and watchers etc. Maybe, coincidentally, something happened in your application to trigger a digest at just that moment and you don't see the issue, but most of the time you will.

A 'better' solution might be to write a wrapper around websocket that calls $rootScope.$digest after whatever callback you have there runs. If you aren't doing it too much then it's probably fine to go like this though.

Comment: Thanks, I've not quite progressed into wrappers yet, so would need to figure out what $rootScope and $digest are. Soon though!

Comment: Oh by wrapper I meant some kind of service where you register the websocket with callbacks, and make sure $rootScope.$digest gets called after. There should be good articles about those two, but the short of it is $rootScope is the highest $scope in your application, and $digest tells angular to check all the bindings, and if the variables have changed, update views etc.